# Proto-Indo-European protowriting?

Tags: proto-indo-european

The Mesopotamians had their own writing system. The Mesopotamians are said to have invented the wheel. The reconstructed vocabulary of the Proto-Indo-Europeans indicates that they had wheels. There is no vocabulary that I know of that indicates writing (they could have a word that means "to record" or something like it), but the way that the wheel spread made me think the Proto-Indo-Europeans had a simpler, older version of cuneiform.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Whether there's any evidence of this?

Comment: Could the Mesopotamian writing have been originally Proto-Indo-European?

Comment: perhaps they had no need for message writing, if whoever delivered the message could simply tell it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A number of people lived in Mesopotamia, including the Sumerians, Kassites, Akkadians, Amorites and other Semitic-speaking people, and Persians. Cuneiform writing was invented by the Sumerians, and widely adopted by many cultures including the Iranians and the Hittites (and their kin), a number of years later. But Indo-European presence in Mesopotamia (which is different from Anatolia) is a more recent and limited historical development. It is implausible that they had a writing system which left no trace, inspired the Sumerian development of their hieroglyphics (whence cuneiform), then re-adapted it millenia later when the Hittites picked up this writing system from Assyrians to the south-east.

Comment: I don't see why a) "It is implausible that they had a writing-system which left no traces ...", although most materials detoriate rather quickly; also, there's Vinča symbols (c.p. Tamga). Writing is not necessarily textual. b) "... inspired the Sumerian development ...", e.g. in the so called Proto-Euphratic hypothesis. lulz c) "... then re-adapted it millenia later", one-and a half, not that many, stranger things have happened. Other than that, I wouldn't dare to call you wrong.